# Replace the "Welcome to Orchard" Dashboard page

Tags: orchardcms-1.8

I'm trying to change the default "Welcome to Orchard" Dashboard page to a custom Dashboard page in a separate module.

How can I do this, if possible?.

I've been looking for an answer for a few hours and all I could find was how to add a custom admin page.

Comment: I have copied the dashboard to a new module I have made and edited a few things on the Index page, but I have no idea how I can redirect or replace the default page so it will show my version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it myself after a while. All i needed to do was add a line in the AdminController of my module.

```
[OrchardSuppressDependency("Orchard.Core.Dashboard.Controllers.AdminController")]
```

Above the `public class AdminController : Controller`

Comment: The other thing you could do is just override the Dashboard view. Create a new view under your theme: mytheme/views/dashboard/admin/index.cshtml

Comment: Or, maybe the best solution, add a Routes.cs that routes to your custom controller with a higher priority than the default one

Answer (score 1):

> override /themes/mytheme/views/dashboard/admin/index.cshtml

did the trick.